# Fibered category with cleavage is a pseudofunctor

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

I'm following [Vistoli's note](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf) on fibered categories and stacks. There Proposition 3.11 he states, which as I understand is a classical result with many references, which says $-$

> A fibered category over $\mathcal{C}$ with a cleavage defines a pseudo-
> functor on $\mathcal{C}$.

But as is the issue with such classical results, I'm yet to find a full proof of this fact, and everyone mostly gives sketches, as does Vistoli. I decided to write a whole proof myself, and I'm having some issues :

- consider a fibered category $F:\cal{F}\to\cal{C}$ with a cleavage. This means we have unique pullbacks for every morphism in the base. With this information, I define a pseudofunctor $\Phi : \cal{C}\to Cat$.
- For an object $x\in \cal{C}$, $\Phi(x)$ is just the fiber category of the functor $F$ over the object $x$ and the morphism $id_x$.
- For a morphism $a:x\to y$, $\Phi(a):\Phi(y)\to\Phi(x)$ is a functor. We take any object $B$ over $y$, and using the morphism $x\to y$ we can pullback $B$ to an object $A$ over $x$, using our cleavage. This defines $\Phi(a)$ on objects, and on morphisms, if $\alpha:B_1\to B_2$ is a morphism, then $\Phi(a)(\alpha):\Phi(a)(B_1)\to \Phi(a)(B_2)$ is the morphism which can be defined as a lift; as $\Phi(a)(B_2)\to B_2$ is cartesian.
- Now to the $2$-morphisms. Let $x\xrightarrow{a}y\xrightarrow{b}z$ be two composable arrows. We have to define a natural transformation between functors $\Phi(a)\Phi(b)\implies \Phi(ba):\Phi(z)\to \Phi(x)$. This is the part I'm having issues with. I have been able to define a morphism between $$\Phi(a)\Phi(b)(Z)\to \Phi(ba)(Z)$$ for any object $Z$ in $\Phi(z)$. But I don't know how to show this actually gives a natural transformation. As in now I would have to show the naturality square for this natural transformation commutes. For this I would need to choose a morphism $Z_1\to Z_2$ in $\Phi(z)$ and look at the relevant square. I feel like this again would require the cartesianness of $\Phi(ba)(Z_2)\to Z_2$ but not sure how to write a complete proof. To apply the cartesian property, I'm unable to show that there is a factorization downstairs, which I wanted to lift upstairs uniquely, and show both my morphisms are factorizations, hence they're the same by uniqueness.

Can anyone help me with some hints or references? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try having a look at the entry Fibred Categories in The Stacks Project, it may have the details you want though I don't think they use the language of cleavages.